# DBT - best practices on schema to which the dbt deployed models should belong to?

Tags: materialized-views, azure-synapse, dbt, fishtown-analytics, common-schema

I am working on a database intensive project where there are lots of schemas and tables/views etc that are created in these schemas.

My question is around the best practice or recommended practice on to what schema should all the DBT deployed models should belong to?

One option is to have them belong to different schemas based on its definition.

Other option is to have them all belong to same schema that is separate from the other schemas already existing in the database, so we can lookup using the particular schema name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking a great question! Albiet, one without one right answer.

From the [dbt docs's Using Aliases page](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-aliases#why-alias-model-names):

> The names of schemas and tables are effectively the "user interface" of your data warehouse. Well-named schemas and tables can help provide clarity and direction for consumers of this data. In combination with [custom schemas](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas), model aliasing is a powerful mechanism for designing your warehouse.

Perhaps the answer is:

> Do what you think is best for your users. You are making a library. what's the easiest way for folks to find what they are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its has helped with enough insight to proceed further.